# How to submit to Google Forms?

Tags: android, google-forms

I'm trying to submit data to Google Forms, specifically to [this form here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1EqlHV7Khlb-eONO0ffa_bXEMDcvIzXObt72pnydfW0o/viewform). Here's the code that I'm trying to use to submit to the form. The code executes just fine, but I never see any data show up in the form. Furthermore, the post always returns a status code 200 (Checked later on in the code). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1EqlHV7Khlb-eONO0ffa_bXEMDcvIzXObt72pnydfW0o/formResponse");

List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1840528687",gridSquare));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.406732602",sourceDb));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.369248655",errorType));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry_331766136",paidUserString));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.240391797",version));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("draftResponse","[]\n"));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pageHistory","0"));
results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbzx","1608817002751623479"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));

HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I'm doing it exactly right, except that I was using the wrong values as inputs. Essentially I mixed `sourceDb` and `errorType` when I was setting them. To figure this out, I put the output into a simple web view, which when it executed showed me that the form didn't submit.